# Assembly code to find null values in an array (Using emu8086)

Tags: arrays, assembly, null, emu8086

I'm new here and a total noob to assembly so please bear that in mind ;)

Alright on to the thick of it, I am presented with this piece of assembly code which is suppose to count the number of null values:

```
   MOV CX, 100h 
   MOV BX, 0000h 
   MOV SI, 200h 
Etq2 : CMP [SI], 0 
     JNZ Etq1 
     INC BX 
Etq1 : INC SI 
     DEC CX 
     JNZ Etq2 
     MOV [400], BX 
HLT
```

I am asked to put the following numbers in an array(table?) [1,3,0,5,0,0,6,0,9,0] run the code and give the contents of BX to validate.

What I understand is:
The array(table) size is 100h 
It starts at 200h.
The results will be placed in 400h.

What I **don't get** is how do I introduce the numbers in the array? I've googled like crazy and I can't make heads or tails of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition to my answer below, [this looks to be a good instruction reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/). There seem to be many varieties of the `MOV` instruction for storing stuff into a memory location (IBM Assembler has an explicit `ST` (Store) instruction for moving register contents into memory locations, so that's initially what I was looking for here, but it seems like `MOV` will do it).

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the insight!

I ended up doing the following:

```
org 100h

.data
array db 1,3,0,5,0,0,6,0,9,0

   .code
    MOV CX, 0Ah               ;10 is the size of the array I am given
    MOV BX,0000h 
    MOV SI, 200h
    LEA SI,array
Etq2:   
        CMP [SI], 0
JNE Etq1 
        INC BX 
Etq1:
        INC SI 
        DEC CX 
        JNE Etq2 
        MOV [400], BX 
        HLT
```

My BX turns out to be 5 which is the correct number of 0's in my array..

I hope the teacher's happy with this one! :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've never messed with any x86 assembly before, but I have some knowledge of IBM Assembler so I expect the concepts are more or less the same.

My first thought is that you would want some kind of move (`MOV`) instruction that will store the array values into sequential memory locations starting with the first position (`200h` as you state).

Something like `MOV SI,1` for the first number and `MOV SI+1,3` for the second number, etc. assuming each of the array's numbers is 1 byte in size.

Sorry for the multiple edits here, but I think I've wrapped my head around this now.

Comment: I think the OP is supposed to have the array as *static* data in the `.data` or `.rodata` section, like `array: db 1,3,0,5,0,0,6,0,9,0`.  (Like C `static uint8_t array[] = {...}`).  The part they're asking about is looping over that array finding `0` bytes.

Comment: And BTW, the syntax for an x86 memory-destination `mov` instruction is `mov byte ptr [si+1], 3` in this MASM-like flavour of Intel syntax.  The `byte ptr` is necessary because neither operand is a register (memory, immediate), so neither implies an operand size of byte or word.  Some bad assemblers like emu8086 default to byte, I think, which is why the OP's `CMP [SI], 0` assembles instead of being rejected as ambiguous.  Or if it defaults to `word` then it's only going to set ZF when SI points to the two contiguous 0 bytes.  (An x86 "word" = 2 bytes, a dword = double word = 4 bytes.)

Comment: Wow, good to know. Really, a word is 2 bytes in this architecture? That makes it so much more confusing.

Comment: In x86 documentation, yes `word` means 2 bytes.  Remember that x86-64 evolved out of 16-bit 8086.  Instead of redefining the terminology for describing 16-bit mode and operand-size (which 386 and later CPUs still support), Intel just kept calling 32-bit quantities a `dword`.  So an x86 `word` has nothing to do with "machine word size", register widths, bus widths, or anything like you might be used to from thinking about a MIPS or a classic PowerPC as word-oriented architectures. See [an answer and my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/99027933) - the current version looks good